# Eliminar js y css innecesario de wordpres

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome

Mi pregunta es basica pues soy autoditacta y principiante, pero es posible identificar los js a eliminar el script desde  el navegador asi?

62/102 request significa que la mitad de los recursos no los usa esa pagina?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Time: 0ms, significa que no se cargan en la web y puedo deshabilitarlos?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano!
Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas en *Google dev tools*.

***Request*** son "peticiones". Las páginas *piden* al servidor ficheros con HTML, CSS, JS, imagenes, ... Todo lo necesario para visualizar la página, aquello que la compone. Normalmente son cosas que se usan, pero no necesariamente: podemos "dejar" un link de carga de un fichero CSS que no usamos, por ejemplo. Con lo que estamos descargando algo *innecesario*.

***Time*** se refiere al tiempo que tarda el navegador en descargar cada recurso.
Puede estar cacheado (ya almacenado en tu navegador) con lo que el tiempo es 0, o lo más probable tu web esta en local por lo que la carga de ficheros es automática.

Comment: Entiendo entonces que dev tools de google no muestra los js sin usar pero si cargados en el sitio (por ejemplo por plugins), conoces una metodología para identificarlos fácilmente?